# Problem adding Memcached support in Docker for PHP8.1 using bookworm

Tags: php, docker, memcached, libmemcached

I have a `Dockerfile` relying on `PHP:8.1-apache`, running since months.

Once `PHP:8.1-apache` started to use Debian bookworm, the memcached client started to give an error while building the image.

The `Dockerfile` rows involved are

```
FROM php:8.1-apache

...

RUN apt-get update --fix-missing -q \
    && apt-get install -y curl mcrypt gnupg build-essential software-properties-common wget vim zip unzip libxml2-dev libz-dev libpng-dev libmemcached-dev \
    && pecl install memcached \
    && docker-php-ext-enable memcached \

...
```

The error at image build time is:

```
checking for libmemcached location... configure: error: memcached support requires libmemcached. Use --with-libmemcached-dir=<DIR> to specify the prefix where libmemcached headers and library are located
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/memcached/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/bin/php-config --with-libmemcached-dir=no --with-zlib-dir=no --with-system-fastlz=no --enable-memcached-igbinary=no --enable-memcached-msgpack=no --enable-memcached-json=no --enable-memcached-protocol=no --enable-memcached-sasl=yes --enable-memcached-session=yes' failed
```

Pinning the oldstable version solves the problem,

`FROM php:8.1-apache-bullseye`

And that clearly indicates that the issue is caused by the switch to new Debian Version.

What could be done to use `bookworm` and continue to use the same libraries and process ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ensure these libraries are installed (in particular, `libssl-dev`):

```
RUN apt install -y libmemcached-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev
```

Credit to AKorezin: https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/issues/541#issuecomment-1624041385

Then you can follow the usual PECL install process:

```
RUN yes '' | pecl install -f memcached-3.2.0 \
  && docker-php-ext-enable memcached
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this two missing libraries in the Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get install -y libmemcached-dev libmemcached11
```

Comment: Thanks Alez, but sadly the error is still the same